# td's width is ignored

Tags: html, css

I have set `table-layout: fixed`, width and padding for column but real width is higher per 22px than it should be. What can cause this?

[image: illustration]

Comment: Which setting do you mean?

Comment: Technically, if you look, the `<TD>` width is not set. Just the `<TD>`'s image.

Comment: The height includes the padding, so may be you should increase the padding?

Comment: @Qoop I've tried, exactly same result

Comment: Is there any way that you can replicate the issue? "width is higher" doesn't offer up a lot of sense.

Comment: @Qoop I've set width to 68px. The real width of column is 90px. How to make it 68px?

Comment: give me something to play with then i won't just be guessing

Comment: on http://other.dttrading.sk/PRO-DESIGN.htm press the rectangle with green border in the upper right corner. right next to 0€

Comment: @Qoop I'm trying to achieve similar table to pro-design.sk, but with merged columns. If I use style from pro-design.sk, it crashes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have set the table width to 1000px and cell widths in pixels, too, so that they do not add up to 1000px. Obviously, a browser has to make the cells wider or to ignore the setting on the table as a whole. It is better that you as an author make such a choice, e.g. by simply removing the width setting on the table.